# Syntax Error in jQuery script

Tags: jquery

This is my code:

```
$('#<some_object>').on( "keypress", function(event) {
  if (event.which == 13 && !event.shiftKey) {
    event.preventDefault(); 
      $.get('ajax.php', {
        action: '<some_text>',
        customer: ,
        value: $('#<some_object>').val()
      }, function(data) {
        $('#<some_object>').attr('value',data);
      }
    )
  }
});
```

I am having syntax error in majority in browsers, except my dev on which I use chrome. Please help me find the problem.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: `customer: , ` there's an error on the comma (a value is missing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is raising because of,

```
 $.get('ajax.php', {
  action: '<some_text>',
  customer: ,    ------------------------> ERROR FOUND             
  value: $('#<some_object>').val()
 }
```

Try to assign any empty values or even null to it to fix that error. The pointed line makes that object as an invalid one.